# adapting show/hide on click

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to adapt some jquery code I found here to show/hide divs on click, but the example only seems to work by flipping between 2 divs (as pasted below), and I can't figure out how to add a 3rd..simply adding another line to in the on click part obviously isn't working. I understand how the function works at the moment but Im having trouble conceptualizing how to expand it..

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <STYLE>

    #img{padding-left: 10%;
        padding-top: 5%;
        padding-bottom: 5%;
        max-height: 90%;
    float: left;
    }
    #contents{padding-left: 10%;
        padding-right: 10%;
        padding-top: 12%;
    float: left;
    font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: large;
            font-weight:bolder ;
        line-height: 15px;
    } 
    #text1 {font-family: sans-serif;
        padding-top ;
        max-width: 100%;
        padding-bottom: 10%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    float:left;}
    #text2{font-family: sans-serif;
        padding-top;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    float:left;}



    div.hide{display:none;}
    div.show {}

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <p id="img"><img src="http://www.newgalerie.us/cache_img/w400_db77979c2a3abfb62b58e139cbaf39056f.png"></p>
        <p id="contents"> 

    <a onclick="showText('text1','text2')" href="javascript:void(0);">TEXT1</a><br></br>
    <a onclick="showText('text2','text1')" href="javascript:void(0);">TEXT2</a>
    </p>
    <div id="text1" class="hide"> 
            TEXT1   

 </div>
<div id="text2" class="hide"> TEXT2 
</div>
<script>
function showText(show,hide)
{
    document.getElementById(show).className = "show";
    document.getElementById(hide).className = "hide";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: rethink how your code is working, passing parameters in is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: to make my last comment more helpful, you may also want to look at alternatives to using the onclick attribute in your html code.

Comment: seems like the toggle function might be a way forward...digging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, 1st of all, you don't use jquery... is pure javascript :)

You can throw out line with jquery...

2nd. Your code is really messy, and this function is not good solution, but if you only neeed 3 divs, can be ok. This code:

HTML:

```
<p id="img">
    <img src="http://www.newgalerie.us/cache_img/w400_db77979c2a3abfb62b58e139cbaf39056f.png">
</p>
<p id="contents"> <a onclick="showText('text1','text2','text3')" href="javascript:void(0);">TEXT1</a>
    <br></br> <a onclick="showText('text2','text1','text3')" href="javascript:void(0);">TEXT2</a>

    <br></br> <a onclick="showText('text3','text1','text2')" href="javascript:void(0);">TEXT3</a>

</p>
<div id="text1" class="hide">TEXT1</div>
<div id="text2" class="hide">TEXT2</div>
<div id="text3" class="hide">TEXT3</div>
<script>
    function showText(show, hide1, hide2) {
        document.getElementById(show).className = "show";
        document.getElementById(hide1).className = "hide";
        document.getElementById(hide2).className = "hide";
    }
</script>
```

CSS:

```
 #img {
     padding-left: 10%;
     padding-top: 5%;
     padding-bottom: 5%;
     max-height: 90%;
     float: left;
 }
 #contents {
     padding-left: 10%;
     padding-right: 10%;
     padding-top: 12%;
     float: left;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     font-size: large;
     font-weight:bolder;
     line-height: 15px;
 }
 #text1 {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     padding-top;
     max-width: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 10%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     float:left;
 }
 #text2 {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     padding-top;
     max-width: 100%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     float:left;
 }
 #text3 {
     font-family: sans-serif;
     padding-top;
     max-width: 100%;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     float:left;
 }
 div.hide {
     display:none;
 }
 div.show {
 }
```

FIDDLY: http://jsfiddle.net/w8j2t/

Comment: this works and makes sense, just needed to add more hide variables to account for each new div.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the links and divs with something like this:

```
<a class="showDiv" data-targetclass="div1">...</a>
<a class="showDiv" data-targetclass="div2">...</a>

<div class="div1">...</div>
<div class="div2">...</div>
```

Then a simple jQuery function will show the div on click:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.showDiv').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var divClass = '.'+$(this).data('targetclass');
        $(divClass).show();
    });
});
```